# Can I send ETH to Chainlink's fulfillRandomWords callback function?

Tags: solidity, chainlink, chainlink-vrf, msg.value

I have this function that requests random words from `Chainlink VRF`...

```
function requestNFTs(
    address[] memory _variants,
    uint256 _variantsType,
    uint32 _amount,
    address _paymentToken
) external {

    require(_amount > 0, "Amount must be greater than zero");
    require(_variantsType == 1 || _variantsType == 2, "Invalid type: ERC721 = 1 | ERC1155 = 2");
    require(getVariantsTotalRemainingSupply(_variants) >= _amount, "Not enough NFTs left to fulfill request");

    uint256 requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
        keyHash,
        s_subscriptionId,
        requestConfirmations,
        callbackGasLimit,
        _amount
    );

    s_requestIdToRequest[requestId] = Request({
        requestOwner: msg.sender,
        variants: _variants,
        variantsType: _variantsType,
        amount: _amount,
        paymentToken: _paymentToken
    });

    emit NFTRequest(requestId, msg.sender, _variants, _amount);

}
```

And then this other function that gets executed after the random words request is fulfilled...

```
function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 _requestId, uint256[] memory _randomWords) internal override {

    Request memory request = s_requestIdToRequest[_requestId];
    address requestOwner = request.requestOwner;
    address[] memory variants = request.variants;
    uint256 variantsType = request.variantsType;
    uint32 amount = uint32(request.amount);
    address paymentToken = request.paymentToken;
    uint256[] memory allTokenIds = new uint256[](amount);
    address[] memory allVariants = new address[](amount);

    // ALL VARIANTS ARE ERC721
    if(variantsType == 1) {
        if(variants.length == 1) {
            // Use randomWords for color only
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                allVariants[i] = variants[0];
                GMG_ERC721_BaseInterface variant = GMG_ERC721_BaseInterface(variants[0]);
                require(getVariantRemainingSupply(address(variant)) >= 1);
                uint256 mintedId = variant.mintRandomType(requestOwner, _randomWords[i], true, paymentToken);
                allTokenIds[i] = mintedId;
            }
        } else {
            // Use randomWords for both variant and color
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                address randomVariant = pickRandomVariant(variants, _randomWords[i]);
                require(randomVariant != address(0), "Not enough NFTs left to fulfill request");
                allVariants[i] = randomVariant;
                GMG_ERC721_BaseInterface variant = GMG_ERC721_BaseInterface(randomVariant);
                require(getVariantRemainingSupply(address(variant)) >= 1);
                uint256 mintedId = variant.mintRandomType(requestOwner, _randomWords[i], true, paymentToken);
                allTokenIds[i] = mintedId;
            }
        }
    }

    // ALL VARIANTS ARE ERC1155
    if(variantsType == 2) {
        if(variants.length == 1) {
            // Use randomWords for color only
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                allVariants[i] = variants[0];
                GMG_ERC1155_BaseInterface variant = GMG_ERC1155_BaseInterface(variants[0]);
                require(getVariantRemainingSupply(address(variant)) >= 1);
                uint256 mintedId = variant.mintRandomType(requestOwner, _randomWords[i], true, paymentToken);
                allTokenIds[i] = mintedId;
            }
        } else {
            // Use randomWords for both variant and color
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                address randomVariant = pickRandomVariant(variants, _randomWords[i]);
                require(randomVariant != address(0), "Not enough NFTs left to fulfill request");
                allVariants[i] = randomVariant;
                GMG_ERC1155_BaseInterface variant = GMG_ERC1155_BaseInterface(randomVariant);
                require(getVariantRemainingSupply(address(variant)) >= 1);
                uint256 mintedId = variant.mintRandomType(requestOwner, _randomWords[i], true, paymentToken);
                allTokenIds[i] = mintedId;
            }
        }
    }

    emit NFTMintedAll(_requestId, requestOwner, _randomWords, amount, allVariants, allTokenIds);

}
```

The `mintRandomType` function is as follows:

```
function mintRandomType(address _to, uint256 _randomWord, bool _userPays, address _paymentToken) public payable nonReentrant returns(uint256) {
    require(hasRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender), "Caller is not a minter");
    if(_userPays) {
        payMint(_to, _paymentToken, 1);
    }
    uint256 randomTokenType = pickRandomTokenType(_randomWord);
    require(randomTokenType != type(uint256).max, "No more NFTs available for minting");
    uint256 mintedToken = doMint(_to, totalSupply(), randomTokenType);
    return mintedToken;
}
```

And the `payMint` works like this:

```
function payMint(address _minter, address _paymentToken, uint256 _amount) internal {
    require(tokenCost[_paymentToken] > 0, "Payment token not accepted");
    if(_paymentToken == address(0)) {
        require(msg.value >= tokenCost[_paymentToken], "Insufficient value to cover token price");
        (bool sent, ) = checkoutWallet.call{ value: msg.value }("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send native coin");
    } else {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_paymentToken);
        SafeERC20.safeTransferFrom(
            token,
            _minter,
            checkoutWallet,
            tokenCost[_paymentToken] * _amount
        );
    }
}
```

Is it possible to set `msg.value` in the function that comes back from `Chainlink VRF` (`fulfillRandomWords`) so I can then `mintRandomType` using ETH? Or how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possibility of sending ether (msg.value) from the Chainlinj VRF callback.

A possible workaround if I understand your code would be to make `requestNFTs` payable, then as you are already keeping track of the amount at
 `s_requestIdToRequest[requestId]` and as the contract hold the ether, when the VFR callback happens you can mint.

Hope it helps